# Sharepoint 2013 wrong URL display to users

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I have a newly installed sharepoint 2013, with a default Sharepoint site, I configured Alternative Access Mappings for it as below:
Internal URL: hxxp://example.com
Zone: Default
Public URL: hxxp://example.com

But in homepage I see some link like "New feed" point to hxxp:_//server_hostname...

And the profile picture has the source url of hxxp://server_local_ip...

I tried some article about AAM, but I can not understand the situation. Restarting the servers a few times didn't help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those links are pointing to MySite that is commonly hosted in a separate Web Application such as http://my.company.com, but it can be elsewhere as well, such as COMPUTER_IP:PORT, if it is so configured.

Verify MySite is set up correctly with correct address and also verify the MySite settings in Central Admin User Profile Service Applications's settings so that they point to the correct MySite address. Latter is the one determining where the links are pointing to.

Comment: Thank you, I re-saved setting user profile service, then the links are correctly rendered.